# Alternating Sum Involving Catalan Numbers

Tags: co.combinatorics, discrete-geometry, binomial-coefficients, triangulations, catalan-numbers

I was wondering if anyone knew how to obtain a simpler closed form of the following sum(or had any other insights regarding it):

$$\sum_{k=0}^n (-1)^k{n \choose k} C_{2n-2-k} $$

Here $C_n = \frac{1}{n+1} {2n \choose n}$ denotes the $n$th Catalan number. For context, this sum is conjectured to be the minimum number of triangulations of a set of $2n$ points in general position, obtained by the 'double circle' point configuration as described [here](https://dccg.upc.edu/people/ferran/almostConvex.pdf).

Comment: Probably if there were a simpler formula it would be in the OEIS entry <https://oeis.org/A086452>.

BTW note that the denominator of C_n is n+1, not 2n+1.

Comment: (Alternatively, the formula with $2n+1$ is $C_n=\frac1{2n+1}\binom{2n+1}n$.)

Comment: It's a discrete convolution: try the product of the corresponding generating functions

Comment: you mean a closed form not involving a hypergeometric function, right?

Comment: That would be preferable, although if anything of interest could be said about the hypergeometric function in question that would be good too.

Comment: I would at first ask for a formula without alternating sum (which is usually more instructive for studying growth etc)

Comment: @PietroMajer I've tried what you suggest but get some sort of Hadamard product rather than convolution: note that the $n$th binomial must be matched with coefficients of the Catalan series from $n-2$nd to $2n-2$nd. Or did you mean something simpler? See my attempt at answer, feel free to modify it in any way if you want.

Answer (score 4):

It is hard to define "closed form" without knowing your audience. Let's say we have a closed form if it looks something like the sum
$$\sum_{k=0}^n\binom{n}k^2=\binom{2n}n.$$
In this context, there is no closed form for the sequence
$$a_n:=\sum_{k=0}^n(-1)^k\binom{n}k\,C_{2n-k-2}$$
because the minimal "annihilating" operator is of second order
\begin{align*}
&-6(7n + 4)(2n - 3)(n + 1)a_n + (-329n^3 - 181n^2 - 20n + 12)a_{n+1} \\
&\qquad \qquad + 2(7n - 3)(2n + 3)(n + 1)a_{n+2}=0
\end{align*}
instead of being first order.

**Postscript** (a comment on Richard Stanley's comment).

You did strengthen my point on "knowing the audience". But, just for the sake of extending the discussion, perhaps we could say this:

(1) in a sense, yes, the above convention (not its reasoning) excludes the cute example $b_n:=n!+2^n$ while the assumption implies the RHS be "hypergeometric";

(2) in a sense, no, because there is a feel for "irreducibility" in the minimal polynomial for the OP's $a_n$, while your $b_n$ is annihilated by
$$2n(n + 1)b_n - (n^2 + 3n - 2)b_{n+1} +(n-1)b_{n+2}=0$$
which, in fact, is reducible (being mindful of the field)
$$((n-1)N-n(n+1))(N-2) \, b_n=0$$
where $N f(n)=f(n+1)$ is the *forward shift* operator.

Comment: By this reasoning, an expression such as $n!+2^n$ would not be a closed form.

Answer (score 3):

For the record, Mathematica yields
$$
\sum_{k=0}^n (-1)^k{n \choose k} C_{2n-2-k} = C_{2n-2} \ \cdot \ 
{}_2 F_1 \left(1-2n,-n,\frac{5}{2}-2n,\frac{1}{4} \right)
$$

Comment: yes, that is the hypergeometric representation listed in the OEIS entry <oeis.org/A086452> (with an offset of 2)

Answer (score 1):

This is more of a comment, - trying to follow the suggestion of Pietro Majer in a comment and represent the sum using convolutions.

What I get is
$$
\sum_{k=0}^n (-1)^k{n \choose k} C_{2n-2-k}=\mathop{\mathrm{Res}}_{z=0}\left([t^{2n}]\frac{\left(1-\sqrt{1-4\frac tz}\right)\left(1-\frac tz\right)}{2(1-z^2+zt)}\right).
$$

I don't know whether one might conclude from this the equality of the generating functions, i. e. $\sum_{n=0}^\infty\sum_{k=0}^n (-1)^k{n \choose k} C_{2n-2-k}t^{2n}=\mathop{\mathrm{Res}}_{z=0}\frac{\left(1-\sqrt{1-4\frac tz}\right)\left(1-\frac tz\right)}{2(1-z^2+zt)}$. Neither do I know how to calculate the last residue.